# how to reuse LU decomposition in sympy for solving Mx = b for constant M and varying b

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

The easiest way to solve Mx=b for matrices in sympy is [`M.LUsolve(b)`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.Matrix.LUsolve). Is there a way to reuse the LU decomposition, if I have a lot of equations with constant M and varying b? I don't see one.

Comment: Would it be fast enough to use the `LUdecomposition()` to obtain the `L` and `U` matrices, and then sequentially solve `Mx=b` with `Ly = b` and then `Ux = y`?

Comment: That's what I was planning to do at a high level, but I don't see any builtin functions to do elimination solving with `Ly = b` and `Ux = y` for lower and upper triangular matrices.

Comment: I was hoping sympy would recognize triangular matrices and solve them more efficiently, but it looks like `U.LUsolve(L.LUsolve(b))` is actually slower.

Comment: There are [lower](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html?highlight=lower_triangular_solve#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.lower_triangular_solve) / [upper_triangular_solve](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html?highlight=lower_triangular_solve#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.upper_triangular_solve) which might help.

Comment: kalhartt: turn it into an answer and I'll accept. Somehow I missed those.